# I want to sync google calendar events after login with google javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-calendar-api

I am using this code to directly authenticate user and syncing google calendar events.

```
const handleClick = () => {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      console.log('loaded client')

      gapi.client.init({
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES,
      })

      gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('bam!'))

      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
      .then(async () => {
        
        /*
            Uncomment the following block to get events
        */
        // get events
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
        }).then((response : any) => {
          const events = response.result.items
          console.log('EVENTS: ', events)
        })
      })
    })}
```

But I want to access events from the access token we get after login with google.

**Here is the google for google login:**

```
<GoogleLogin
  clientId="clientID"
  buttonText="Login"
  onSuccess={responseGoogle}
  onFailure={responseGoogle}
  cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
/>
```

I simply want to login with google and then access the google calendar to get and play with google calendar events.

I'm currently doing this through react. If anyone can recommend through the backend that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getBasicProfile(), '##')
```

this can give us the basic profile of the after authentication